# Angular4+ and Asp.NET Core with a redirect response

Tags: angular, http, asp.net-core, redirect, angular-services

I have a ASP.NET Core Api  with a Post method in a Controller and an angular service that makes a call to it
Till today I make navigation from within angular with the router, but I need to know if its possible and how to redirect from the server and handle this situation on angular Post method that will receive a redirect response and not some JSON object. Can the browser handle this by itself or I need to do something within the call after receiving the response?

client and server running on the same server

Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Post([FromBody]string myvalue)  

    {

    // some operations here

        string parameter = SomeFunctionReturningParameter(myvalue);

            return new RedirectResult("/component2?param=" + parameter);
        }


    }
```

Angular service

```
public callRedirection(apiEnd:, body: any): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.post(endPoint, body)
      .map((response) => {

    //how to handle redirect here  
        return response; 
      })
     .catch(error => {  console.log(error) });
  }
```

Any Idea???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to import the Router into your component and in the handler extract the route and navigate to the url.

```
import { Router } from '@angular.router';

...

constructor(private router: Router...) {
...
}

public callRedirection(apiEnd:, body: any): Observable<any> {

return this.http.post(endPoint, body)
  .map((response) => {

    //how to handle redirect here  
    this.router.navigate(response.url)

  })
 .catch(error => {  console.log(error) });
```

}

NOTE: I'm not 100% sure how to get the URL from the response, but I'm sure you can work it out in the debugger :-)

Comment: Works when I'm running server and client on the same server, but throwing an error when running both separately. Anyways the answer is good

Comment: You are only returning a part of the Url from the server so Angular will assume the redirect is on the same server. Change your server to return the full URL e.g. 
return new RedirectResult("http://myhost/component2?param=" + parameter);

Comment: That comment has marked out the Http at the start of the redirect address :-( It should start with "Http://" and then the full URL e.g. myHost/Component  etc.